# eBay API get Store ID in Product Listing

Tags: php, ebay-api

Currently I am using eBay product finding API. I have tried to call finding API in PHP and got the list of all products, but I also want store id/name in this list.

How can I get store id/name for each product in the listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the *outputSelect* field in your request has been set to *StoreInfo* as mentioned in the eBay [docs](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Request.outputSelector). This ensures that the API will return the [storeInfo](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Response.searchResult.item.storeInfo) element which contains the store name and URL.